# Microsoft Graph API Pagination Users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync() return error with message Invalid next page search request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to pull B2C users from the next page but gets the following error:
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Invalid next page search request.
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2021-07-08T20:25:20
request-id: 7fd74717-0f7b-467f-9753-64c416fe5902
client-request-id: 7fd74717-0f7b-467f-9753-64c416fe5902
ClientRequestId: 7fd74717-0f7b-467f-9753-64c416fe5902

The problem is I'm using the same code to get AAD users and it works but somehow doesn't for B2C users!!
here is the code I'm using:

```
    //read B2C
ClientCredentialProvider authProviderB2C = new(this.B2CClientApp);

// Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient in B2C with the authentication provider.
GraphServiceClient graphClientB2C = new(authProviderB2C);

var b2cUsers = await graphClientB2C.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuer eq '{AppSettingsProvider.AADIssuer}')")
                    .Top(999)
                    .Select(u => new {
                        u.DisplayName,
                        u.Id,
                        u.Mail,
                        u.UserPrincipalName,
                        u.Identities
                    })
                    .GetAsync();

// Create a bucket to hold the final B2C users result
var b2cUserList = new List<User>();

// Add the first page of data to the final B2C user list
b2cUserList.AddRange(b2cUsers.CurrentPage);

// Repeate until all pages have been returned
while (b2cUsers.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    b2cUsers = await b2cUsers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    b2cUserList.AddRange(b2cUsers.CurrentPage);
}
```

It gives me the above error when calling b2cUsers = await b2cUsers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Before building the code, i always test the API calls with Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN to see if it works for me or not. I would suggest you the same.

Comment: @Dev Thank you. I do use both to test but didn't know how to send a request for the second page in POSTAM. Anyway the issue is that the filter with identities somehow doesn't support paging even though  NextPageRequest is there and != null. So as a workaround I changed my filter to a something that supported paging.

Comment: Glad that it helped @Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the filter with identities somehow doesn't support paging even though NextPageRequest is there and != null.